# Где удобнее парсить?

Tags: android, архитектура, jsoup

Имеется проект приложения, работающего на парсинге. Так как язык - Java, инструмент для парсинга был выбран Jsoup. Очень удобный юзабилити, но получилось очень много кода, как его не сокращай.

Есть идея вынести парсинг на бекенд и работать с HTML там, а приложению отдавать удобный JSON. Стоит ли это делать, разве на PHP есть что-то похожее на Jsoup?

И еще такой минус: загрузка будет дольше - один запрос на бекенд, второй запрос - от бекенда на конечную "цель".

Comment: Зачем лишний раз сервак грузить.

Comment: В идеале как раз таки сервер и должен все парсить и на клиент возвращать готовый json, как в вашем примере. Но запрос должен быть один. Зачем их вам два? Я не спец в php, но если загуглить 'php parse html' то первый результат вам подходит. JSoup либа отличная, но на клиенте парсинг занимает больше времени нежели на бэкенде.

Comment: @АндроидАндроид, Запроса два, потому что бэкенд тоже данные должен откуда-то получать.

Comment: Идея выноса парсинга на бэкенд хороша всем, кроме масштабируемости. А лучше всего, чтобы бэкенд выступал в качестве кэша (например, раз в 5 минут запрашивал данные откуда-то и складывал себе, если это не критично для приложения).

Comment: @post_zeew, в моем случае это игра. данные непостоянные, естественно. так что, не избежать "двузапросности"